# Spinner inside Keyboard View of soft keyboard for android - It is possible?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-spinner

My question is quite simple and I won't attach all my code because that would be boring and difficult to understand and complain for those who know java not as me (Yea, I'm sooo new in Android Developing, well in developing in fact).

**So my question is:**

> I'm trying to develop a semi automatic translator integrated to a custom keyboard with custom keys, BUT I don't know how to get rid with adding the spinners that contains the language selectors to my keyboard.

I tried it including it with onKey but it doesn't work. 
"mentioned code"

```
    case KEYCODE_SPINNER_1:

            EnterLan = new Spinner(this);
            EnterLan.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, GetAllValues()));
            EnterLan = (Spinner) EnterLan.findViewById(R.id.sTobeTranslated);
            break;
```

Although it doesn't crush the Spinner doesn't show up.

ALL HELP IS WELL RECEIVED!

Thanks a lot,

SoftWario

Comment: You have to add the Spinner to your layout...

Comment: But which layout? I mean I have tested to have it the spinner in a linearlayout apart from the KeyboardView layout, alone in another layout, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: BTw, thanks for answering ;D

Comment: I mean after you do `EnterLan = new Spinner(this);` you have to do something like `keyboardLayout.addView(EnterLan);` for it to show up...

Comment: Okay... So I think too there it should be the problem but how do i get the EnterLan shown?